# Replace div content using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code in `header.html`:

```
<nav role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a id="home" href="index.html" class="current">home</a></li>
        <li><a id="about" href="includes/test.html">about</a></li>
        <li><a id="resources" href="#">resources</a></li>
        <li><a id="archive" href="#">archives</a></li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

Now, everything seems fine until my `index.html` loads files from another folder to fill the divs with `id="header"`, `id="content"` and `id="footer"` using:

```
$(function() {
    $("#mainhead").load("templates/header.html");
    $("#content").load("templates/content.html");
    $("#footer").load("templates/footer.html");
});
```

My question is - How can I replace content in the div `id="content"` with the one from another HTML page that can be accessed by clicking a link in the nav menu?

Comment: Do you have to contents that you want to put into the div as a string?

Comment: Is `$('nav a').click(function() { $('#content').load(this.href) });` what you mean?

Comment: my guess is you would put load calls similar to this in a click handler, and attach that to the `click` event of the menu item?

Comment: Load the content onclick and not on document ready.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the code that loads the navigation to this...

```
$("#mainhead").load("templates/header.html", function() {
    $(this).find(".nav a").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();             // stop the link from firing as normal
        $("#content").load(this.href);  // load the file specified by the link
    });
});
```

This will "ajaxify" the links in the header navigation, after it has loaded, so that the content div is loaded for each of the links, without having to navigate away from the page.  Just make sure each header link has the correct `href` value for the content you want it to load.

Comment: Thank you very much, worked like charm, it's been two days since I was looking for a solution, but nothing seemed to work, thank you very much again

Comment: No problem - glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

> $("#content").replace("old page","new page");

try this one.

or

> $("#content").load(){
>         location.replace("your page");
>           }

or

> var url = "Your url"; $(location).attr('href',url);

Comment: tried this one too, didn't help much either, thank your for the answer though :D

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant? This will load the content from header/content/footer pages and load in the appropriate div on click of home.

```
$("#home").click(function () {
    $("#mainhead").load("templates/header.html", function (data) { $(this).html(data); });
    $("#content").load("templates/content.html", function (data) { $(this).html(data); });
    $("#footer").load("templates/footer.html", function (data) { $(this).html(data); });
});
```

Comment: already done that, the problem was when i wanted to change to another page (like "about", "resources", etc) to not redirect me to that page, but to replace the actual content in the #content div with the one from the "about" page.

Answer (score -2):

```
$("#div").html("Your content");
```